Rewiring Bathroom switches as Combined Switch and Only Switch
I have two 2 single pole switches in bathroom, where one is for light and other for exhaust fan.

LS-A & LS-B are two terminals for Light Switch 1

WL-H is Light Hot Wire and WL-L is Light Load Wire


FS-A & FS-B are two terminals for Fan Switch 2

WF-H is Fan Hot Wire and WF-L is Fan Load Wire



Can I rewire the switches in such a way that

Switch 1 turns on both light and fan and
Switch 2 turns on fan only (no matter whether Switch 1 is on or off).

Can we accomplish this?
On a Fun Note, I posted this to ChatGPT, Claude and Gemini and none of them were able to answer it without mistakes :)
The real reason I wanted to do this is because I have a new Switch 1 that is actually motion activated single pole switch. I wanted both light and fan to turn on as soon as someone enters the bathroom. And additionally if I want only the fan to be turned on for another 30 minutes, I can do it with Switch 2

Is this a question or a test?

Do not know about you, but I think I would use the light only about half the time without needing the fan on.  Your way would need the fan on every time the light is needed.

I cannot think of a way to do this without using a diode. I also cannot think of a practical use for this set up.

If you know enough that ChatGPT made mistakes about this connection, what else is known?

A "2 pole" switch is a single switch which controls 2 separate circuits, but it seems like you're using the term to refer to a single switch with 2 terminals for controlling a single circuit. The former would be extremely unusual to find in a residential bathroom while the latter would be perfectly normal.

Thank you for all the quick responses. It is a single pole switch with an extra ground. I don't think it is possible, but definitely felt this question was something that none of the "intelligent AI" could answer. Humans are safe. I am good with it as separate switches. I will edit my question with the reason for this setup

You called the switches 2-pole, but as described, they're actually 2-terminal or single-pole switches. Your objective can be met with a switch that truly is 2-pole. Leviton CS220 is an example of such. You'll note that a 2-pole switch has four screws and looks like a "4-way" switch, but the internal connections are different.
The new 2-pole and existing 1-pole switch can be wired as below:


How is this any different from just using 2 "regular" single-pole switches in parallel?Another way to distinguish 2-pole and 4-way switches is that 2-pole switches typically have "On" and "Off" markings, whereas 4-way switches do not.

@kreemoweet If the fan and the light are both connected to the one output of a single-pole switch then it's impossible to operate them separately - any attempt to energize one energizes both because they're tied together at that switch connector. The two-pole switch occupies one space in the junction box and is operated with a single motion, but the critical difference is that it keeps the fan and the light electrically separate.

Thank you I think this is the right answer. I have a 2 pole moition activated light switch and I think it is not possible to setup with my current switches. Thank you for your help

As mentioned by @GregHill, I need a special 2 pole switch for this setup.

All AI Tool got this part wrong, and was concluding the as @kreemoweet thought, which I also believed initially as correct

@user243302 Regarding the additional detail of the motion sensing switch: You could wire the motion-sensing switch so that it powers the light and a relay, then wire the relay so that it and the other 1-pole switch are in parallel to provide power to the fan. This might require additional junction box space.
